# Watir - Handling a new window

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to have a very simple script with Watir, and for some reason can't:

This should login to a website with Twitter.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.start 'http://www.12mass.com/'
browser.link(:class, 'priceLogin').click
sleep 2
browser.element(:class, 'loginTwitter').click
browser.windows.last.use do
        browser.text_field(:id, 'username_or_email').click
        browser.text_field(:id, 'username_or_email').set 'name'
        browser.text_field(:id, 'password').set 'pass'

        browser.button(:id, 'allow').click
    end
```

I get to a point where a new window opens, but I can't reach it and fill the credentials...

Every now an then I get an error (in my log): `rescue in rbuf_fill'.
I already added:

```
require 'net/http' 
http = Net::HTTP.new(@host, @port)
http.read_timeout = 500
```

To my code, but I still get the error and can't log fill the credentials in the new window.

Also, I tried this:

```
browser.windows.last.use
browser.element(:css, '[for="username_or_email"]').click
```

Had the same error..

Comment: "I can't reach it" - not sure what you mean. Reach what?

Comment: Is this a typo in your code? - _browser.window.last_ won't work. It needs to be _browser.windows.last_ ... Also, what is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Thanks Abe, that was -an- issue, but still doesn't work.  I changed that, simulated a click on the label there - doesn't work.  It seems like I can't get any data or fill any fields in that popup.  I've tried several browser.windows.<> techniques..  "last", "index" and title.  non work.

Comment: Jschorr - I can't fill the text fields in the new window.

Comment: The rbuff_fill error is usually an indicator that you have an infinite loop going on somewhere... What happens if you stop using the code block for the second window? It's not strictly necessary to have the code for the second window in the block, as you do.  Just do _browser.windows.last.use_ and then the next lines, without the do...end block around them.

Comment: Abe - You mean something like this:
browser.windows.last.use.text_field(:id, 'username_or_email').click  Didn't work as well...
Also, doing just this: browser.windows.last.use

 browser.element(:css, '[for="username_or_email"]').click
        browser.windows.last.use  
throws the same error.
 browser.element(:css, '[for="username_or_email"]').click

Comment: The problem line is this one: _browser.element(:class, 'loginTwitter').click_

For some reason Watir/Selenium isn't seeing the click as having finished. All the code below that is superfluous to the issue. I'm continuing to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

This is looking very much like a bug in Watir-webdriver or Selenium-webdriver.

The failure occurs when we get to the line

```
browser.element(:class, 'loginTwitter').click
```

Just for my own edification I changed that line to read

```
browser.div(:class_name, 'logBtn loginTwitter').click
```

The error I get is the following:

```
/Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2563:in `read_status_line'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2552:in `read_new'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1320:in `block in transport_request'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `catch'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1317:in `transport_request'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1294:in `request'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1287:in `block in request'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:746:in `start'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in `execute'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:369:in `clickElement'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:54:in `click'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:131:in `click'
    from /Users/abrahamheward/Work/kuality-coeus/lib/kuality-coeus/data_objects/test.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

My guess is that the appearance of the new window is somehow confusing Watir/Selenium.

It might be worthwhile to submit a bug to the Watir-webdriver project on github. https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of handling new windows?  That you can handle one once it's opened?  Any idea of how to bypass this issue? Fix it even?  Another gem?

Comment: In my scripts I deal with new windows opening all the time. There's something unusual about that particular situation. Unfortunately I don't know any more than that.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to see if I can get that window to pop in a different way.. Thanks.